# My WebSocket doesnt work in Opera/Midori

Tags: javascript, websocket

everyone I'm creating an "Object" to manage all information about my socket connection but I've some problems about browser compatibilities

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 socket.connect();

 socket.connection.onopen = function(){
 console.log('Connected '+ socket.connection.readyState);
 //Show 1 for every browser
};

socket.connection.onmessage = function(event){
   console.log('Some message '+event.data);
  //Firefox / Chrome Fine
  //Midori/Opera doesnt show this message (console)
 };
});

var socket ={

dataConnection: {
   url:"myURL",
  param:"myParam"
},
connection: "",
connect: function(){
  try{
    this.connection = new WebSocket(this.dataConnection.url+"/"+this.dataConnection.param);
  }catch(error){
    console.log('Something wrong ' + error.message);
  }
}

};
```

I don't understand Wy It works fine (FF and Chrome), Can you give an advice?

Comment: What version of Opera are you using?

Comment: the latest one  (27.0)

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets

Comment: I got your point @RichardGrant thats why I decided to use socket.io instead the native socket. thx

Comment: Socket.io still uses websockets. It's a bit silly to assume a library doesn't have the same limitations. I would advise against using socket.io for commercial use.

Comment: what do you recommend?